# ¿ Cómo puedo hacer que mi clase usuario sea la que use Django por defecto?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    picture = models.ImageField('Imagen', blank=True, null=True, upload_to=url)
    born_date = models.DateField('Fecha de nacimiento', blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField('Genero', max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='U')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfiles'

    def age(self):
        actual = timezone.now().year
        born_year = self.born_date.year
        return actual - born_year

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

Quiero que el sitio de `Django` use este modelo para la autenticación,

¿Cómo se haría esto?

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo muy fácil [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). Te comento:

Te creas una clase que herede de `AbstractBaseUser`, para seguir con tu ejemplo hacemos:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=url)
    born_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, default='U')
```

Si tienes algún requerimiento especial con la forma en que se salvan o se crean los usuarios te haces tu propio `Manager`, heredando de `BaseUserManager`:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, parametro_raro, password=None):
        # aqui se salvan los usuarios

    def create_superuser(self, email, parametro_raro, password):
        # aqui se salvan superusuarios
```

Y en las settings pones un parámetro:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mi_app.Profile'.
```

Espero que te sirva el ejemplo, aunque te recomiendo que vayas al enlace para que veas la explicación completa.

Comment: ya lo hice pero cuando ejecuto `python manage.py migrate` me da el siguiente error: `Unknown field(s) (last_name, first_name, email) specified for Profile`

Comment: Esa es la razón por la que dejé [el enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). Si cambias el modelo de usuario después de haber creado migraciones tienes que cambiar varias cosas.

Comment: elimine la base de datos y las migraciones anteriores antes de ejecutar el migrate